# Is it possible to Migrate from RHEL 5.11 to RHEL 7.1?

Tags: rhel

I want to upgrade the current RHEL version for one of my production system. The current version is RHEL 5.11. Is it possible to install and migrate old setting to RHEL 7.1 without any challenges?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though not without "challenges".

See [How do I migrate from RHEL5 to RHEL7?](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1211223) A direct upgrade path is not supported by Red Hat, but the linked article contains detailed information about all aspects of the process.

See also [Does Red Hat support upgrades between major versions of Red Hat Enterprise Linux?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964) for general info about upgrades between major versions of RHEL.